# VBE sees Ambigious Name

Tags: vba, oop, excel

Hi So I am just Learning about VB's take on OOP. When testing how `Let`,`Get` methods work I created this dummy class `Class1`, apprarently it cannot be compiled becasue "Ambigious name detected: ~" with this error VBE highlights line 2 of the class(one declaring test_property as Integer).

I don't understand what is a ambigious about it?

FYI I experiemented by trying to declare that proterty with `Dim` & `Public` none of those methods change anything.

See class `Class1` bellow:

```
Option Explicit
Private testing_property As Integer

Public Property Let testing_property(new_value As Integer)
    MsgBox "Let Box"
    Let testing = new_value
End Property

Public Property Get testing_property(new_value As Integer) As Integer
    MsgBox "Get Box"
End Property
```

I am calling it using following test Sub:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim test_Class As Class1
    Set test_Class = New Class1
    With test_Class
        .testing_property = "1"
        Debug.Print .testing_property
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a duplicate declaration of your Private property variable and your let and get public procedure properties. You should name your variable

```
Private itesting_property As Integer
```

You also have your Let before your Get. You should assign a value before you write it. Also, your Get() should not accept a variable and be dimmed as an integer, and your Let() should accept a variable as an integer and not be dimmed.

```
Public Property Get testing_property() As Integer
    MsgBox "Get Box"
    testing_property = itesting_property
End Property
Public Property Let testing_property(new_value As Integer)
    MsgBox "Let Box"
    itesting_property = new_value
End Property
```